# Get correct path to file in a dependancy

Tags: java

I have a java project, and it imports a module I have wrote. The Java project is called `cg-lambda` and the module is called `cg-core`. `cg-core`is imported as a dependancy in `cg-lambda` e.g.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.cg:cg-core'
    ...
}
```

I have a class in `cg-core` called `ApiConfiguration` which loads and parses a yaml file.

```
package com.cg.config.guice;

public class ApiConfiguration {

    public static ApiConfiguration fromLocation() {

        try {
            String configurationLocation = "src/main/resources/configuration/env_local.yml";

            final String absoluteFile = new File(configurationLocation).getAbsolutePath();
            ....
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    ....
}
```

The yaml files are located at `/Users/mark/repos/server-side/cg-core/src/main/resources/configuration/`

I call `ApiConfiguration.fromLocation()` from a class in `cg-lambda`:

```
import com.cg.config.guice.ApiConfiguration;

public class OrderHandler {    
    public OrderHandler() {
        final ApiConfiguration apiConfiguration =
                    ApiConfiguration.fromLocation();

        ....
        ....
```

When I debug, I see `absoluteFile` is `/Users/mark/repos/server-side/cg-lambda/src/main/resources/configuration/env_local.yml`

I.e. the path is to `cg-lambda`, not `cg-core` - even though ApiConfiguration is in `cg-core`. Is it possible to get the correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the resources will be packaged inside your cg-core module and when your app runs, the path you have provided will not exist.

The correct way to load the file and to get absolute path will be.

```
String configurationLocation = "configuration/env_local.yml";

final String absoluteFile = new File(ApiConfiguration.class.getClassLoader().getResource(configurationFileLocation).getFile()).getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is maven like path naming, so I am guessing that the src/main/resources are treated as resource directory, so You can assume that this is considered a classpath resource, so just use OrderHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("configuration/env_local.yml"); The thing is that it is an InputStream so you will need a different constructor for ApiConfiguration. But still You will not be able to get the path, but just load your resource. And try to do that, as when you package this config in a JAR/WAR it will not be accessible using path.